# Incorporar svg en android

Tags: android, svg

Tengo un arreglo de esta forma:

ImageView img0;

```
        int [] f1={R.drawable.ic_butterfly, R.drawable.ic_butterfly, R.drawable.ic_butterfly, R.drawable.ic_butterfly};
    Random r1=new Random();
    int a1=r1.nextInt(4);
    img0.setImageResource(f1[a1]);
```

he importado butterfly.svg y generó un xml de nombre ic_butterfly dentro de res/drawable, en  el logcat arroja

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File >res/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_butterfly.xml from drawable resource ID >#0x7f060076
>
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File >res/drawable-anydpi-v21/$ic_butterfly__0.xml from color state list resource >ID #0x7f060000
>
> Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line
>   0: invalid drawable tag gradient

código ic_butterfly.xml:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="300.81"
    android:viewportWidth="569.16" android:width="24dp"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:pathData="M126.58,194.33c-0.77,18.1 1.85,24.19 10.95,31.37s14,16.52 23.47,19.42 22.51,10 26.27,17.17 17.71,15.71 25.94,11.38 3.22,-21.34 25.16,-17.3 16.29,-11 19.55,-15.75 40.47,-145.26 40.47,-145.26S141.22,174.49 126.58,194.33Z"/>
    <path android:pathData="M172.31,209.46c3.8,8.9 18.38,18.7 25.41,15.43s9.31,-37.56 13,-41.78S171.35,207.21 172.31,209.46Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="149053.22383238704"
                android:endY="36004.009928779866"
                android:startX="124785.89751461674"
                android:startY="45270.800555939924" android:type="linear">
                <item android:color="#FFFBB03B" android:offset="0.0"/>
                <item android:color="#FFED1C24" android:offset="1.0"/>
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M216.33,186.14c-6.48,17.41 -11.3,41.57 -12.39,44.94s8.81,9.94 10.82,9.76 7.64,-3.21 9.63,-5.75 10.31,-55.05 15.1,-63.41S217.33,183.47 216.33,186.14Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="10712.313098068236"
                android:endY="23186.20463623047"
                android:startX="8394.30330039978"
                android:startY="23186.20463623047" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M230.19,233.08c5.37,-7.67 14.74,-65 15.78,-69.2s29.44,-39 32.54,-40.22 -34.18,113.28 -36,123.16S227.18,237.41 230.19,233.08Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="16901.09370414734"
                android:endY="39227.791661376956"
                android:startX="12229.364813461303"
                android:startY="39227.791661376956" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M139.2,217.08a5.25,3.56 69.1,1 0,6.65 -2.54a5.25,3.56 69.1,1 0,-6.65 2.54z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M151.93,227.73a4.02,3.04 69.11,1 0,5.68 -2.17a4.02,3.04 69.11,1 0,-5.68 2.17z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M166.67,239.72a4.14,3.88 69.1,1 0,7.25 -2.77a4.14,3.88 69.1,1 0,-7.25 2.77z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M170.17,227a3.97,3.45 69.1,1 0,6.45 -2.46a3.97,3.45 69.1,1 0,-6.45 2.46z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M182.99,246.79a5.97,3.31 69.1,1 0,6.18 -2.36a5.97,3.31 69.1,1 0,-6.18 2.36z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M194.73,260.62a6.05,5.05 69.1,1 0,9.44 -3.6a6.05,5.05 69.1,1 0,-9.44 3.6z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M198.61,244.94a4.14,3.44 69.09,1 0,6.43 -2.46a4.14,3.44 69.09,1 0,-6.43 2.46z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M188.15,234.16a3.97,3.4 69.09,1 0,6.35 -2.43a3.97,3.4 69.09,1 0,-6.35 2.43z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M213.66,253.37a3.31,3.59 69.09,1 0,6.71 -2.56a3.31,3.59 69.09,1 0,-6.71 2.56z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M227.06,250.04a4.4,4.49 69.11,1 0,8.39 -3.2a4.4,4.49 69.11,1 0,-8.39 3.2z"/>
    <path android:pathData="M246.74,252.59c0.16,-8.57 3,-20.67 5.22,-27.72s27.12,-92.56 28.72,-95.83S263.29,230.41 250.27,251.23C248.03,254.84 246.71,254.22 246.74,252.59Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="11140.952912979124"
                android:endY="38507.4492791748"
                android:startX="8435.857337265015"
                android:startY="38507.4492791748" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M270.06,79.88C194.19,49.68 110.33,53.41 57,65.46s-66,34.67 -51.33,54.49 25.52,28.1 48.31,33.59 45.28,24.1 57.2,29S146.58,221.06 172.9,211.01 211.98,172.41 234.34,159.75s28.52,-19.76 33.82,-30.66 10.51,-15.84 15.1,-14.64 3.68,-32.16 -0.15,-36S278.71,83.32 270.06,79.88Z"/>
    <path android:pathData="M175.1,103.73c-12.28,11.2 -40.88,29.22 -50,36.25s13.35,25.65 25.38,16.92S203.58,108.55 203.37,103.41 175.1,103.73 175.1,103.73Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="21440.793780593875"
                android:endY="13787.792133331299"
                android:startX="13541.902606124877"
                android:startY="13787.792133331299" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M217.33,105.93c-11.45,10.28 -58.63,55.51 -65.9,61.24s8.11,25.88 20.86,17.46S270.58,104.51 283.35,96.09s-64,9.05 -64,9.05">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="49176.88120552063"
                android:endY="24261.894482269287"
                android:startX="25721.849458847046"
                android:startY="24261.894482269287" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M276.9,86.94c-22.37,-6.63 -71.23,-16.18 -103.84,-10.22s-42.72,-0.36 -22.34,15S276.28,92.31 278.58,91.41 283,88.75 276.9,86.94Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="49121.83437187195"
                android:endY="6489.278750610351"
                android:startX="29431.74709953308"
                android:startY="6489.278750610351" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M140.9,97.28c-13.63,-0.21 -37,19.66 -36.15,24.06s12.6,16.48 18,15.19S164.52,104.41 164.52,104.41 146.85,97.41 140.9,97.28Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="12630.153940505981"
                android:endY="7323.636122360229"
                android:startX="8876.562898025513"
                android:startY="7323.636122360229" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M83.11,75C69.5,79.61 39.58,88.07 38.39,100.41S49.58,104.95 49.58,104.95s29.08,-21.59 39.68,-23.94C87.51,75.69 83.11,75 83.11,75Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="7569.439549026489"
                android:endY="4945.0285181427"
                android:startX="4668.6560599517825"
                android:startY="4945.0285181427" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M85.19,86.63c-13.81,5.54 -39.16,25.9 -37.07,29.89s5.22,5.93 9.86,4.15 34.13,-23.67 36.58,-25.87S91.79,83.98 85.19,86.63Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="7494.592852516174"
                android:endY="5620.6397597503665"
                android:startX="4814.064075431824"
                android:startY="5620.6397597503665" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M69.39,125.78c6.46,-14.44 29.16,-27.1 35.08,-28.77s-1,9.28 -3.67,14.12S74.68,134.99 73.14,135.58 63.97,137.9 69.39,125.78Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="7258.968316726685"
                android:endY="6999.219652175903"
                android:startX="4961.642607345581"
                android:startY="6999.219652175903" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M28.9,89.6a5,8.31 69.1,1 0,15.53 -5.93a5,8.31 69.1,1 0,-15.53 5.93z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M38.84,77.72a3.31,5.52 69.09,1 0,10.31 -3.94a3.31,5.52 69.09,1 0,-10.31 3.94z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M18.85,107.04a4.6,8.84 69.1,1 0,16.52 -6.31a4.6,8.84 69.1,1 0,-16.52 6.31z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M33.67,125.42a4.24,8.31 69.1,1 0,15.53 -5.93a4.24,8.31 69.1,1 0,-15.53 5.93z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M48.55,135.7a4.05,7.37 69.09,1 0,13.77 -5.26a4.05,7.37 69.09,1 0,-13.77 5.26z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M80.93,139.69a5.25,9.11 69.09,1 0,17.02 -6.5a5.25,9.11 69.09,1 0,-17.02 6.5z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M99.34,147.75a3.04,8.84 69.1,1 0,16.52 -6.31a3.04,8.84 69.1,1 0,-16.52 6.31z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M106.62,162.11a3.04,7.21 69.09,1 0,13.47 -5.15a3.04,7.21 69.09,1 0,-13.47 5.15z"/>
    <path android:pathData="M96.9,88.26a7.55,8.38 69.1,1 0,15.66 -5.98a7.55,8.38 69.1,1 0,-15.66 5.98z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="3402.86078911629"
                android:endY="1112.6840175597988"
                android:startX="3138.3880319007008"
                android:startY="1213.676340966681" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M118.28,93.09a4.24,8.22 69.09,1 0,15.36 -5.87a4.24,8.22 69.09,1 0,-15.36 5.87z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="3323.4605265966893"
                android:endY="439.13315650599543"
                android:startX="3077.5718788809236"
                android:startY="533.0780767110572" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M127.27,75.62a4.66,7.1 69.1,1 0,13.27 -5.07a4.66,7.1 69.1,1 0,-13.27 5.07z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="3106.846001866653"
                android:endY="402.10880503499175"
                android:startX="2921.3467881435104"
                android:startY="472.944065276101" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M15.64,118.24a2.82,4.24 69.1,1 0,7.92 -3.03a2.82,4.24 69.1,1 0,-7.92 3.03z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M8.44,106.09a2.39,4.05 69.1,1 0,7.57 -2.89a2.39,4.05 69.1,1 0,-7.57 2.89z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M6.34,97.42a2.03,5.52 69.09,1 0,10.31 -3.94a2.03,5.52 69.09,1 0,-10.31 3.94z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M26.15,134.16a2.62,5.66 69.1,1 0,10.58 -4.04a2.62,5.66 69.1,1 0,-10.58 4.04z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M36.98,139.19a2.35,4.28 69.1,1 0,8 -3.05a2.35,4.28 69.1,1 0,-8 3.05z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M48.19,146.58a2.35,4.83 69.1,1 0,9.02 -3.45a2.35,4.83 69.1,1 0,-9.02 3.45z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M59.84,146.87a2.49,4.56 69.1,1 0,8.52 -3.25a2.49,4.56 69.1,1 0,-8.52 3.25z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M76.93,154.07a3.47,6.08 69.1,1 0,11.36 -4.34a3.47,6.08 69.1,1 0,-11.36 4.34z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M92.77,159.71a2.49,6.04 69.09,1 0,11.28 -4.31a2.49,6.04 69.09,1 0,-11.28 4.31z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M104.51,174.15a4.42,6.25 69.1,1 0,11.68 -4.46a4.42,6.25 69.1,1 0,-11.68 4.46z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M122.05,181.35a3.59,5.21 69.09,1 0,9.73 -3.72a3.59,5.21 69.09,1 0,-9.73 3.72z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M131.33,171.9a3.73,5.39 69.1,1 0,10.07 -3.85a3.73,5.39 69.1,1 0,-10.07 3.85z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M136.17,191.93a3.45,4.97 69.1,1 0,9.29 -3.55a3.45,4.97 69.1,1 0,-9.29 3.55z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M152.25,201.45a3.73,5.52 69.1,1 0,10.31 -3.94a3.73,5.52 69.1,1 0,-10.31 3.94z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M88.86,75.06a3.59,5.8 69.09,1 0,10.84 -4.14a3.59,5.8 69.09,1 0,-10.84 4.14z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M103.41,66.48a2.83,5.1 69.09,1 0,9.53 -3.64a2.83,5.1 69.09,1 0,-9.53 3.64z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M139.96,64.12a3.22,4.97 69.1,1 0,9.29 -3.55a3.22,4.97 69.1,1 0,-9.29 3.55z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M173.49,67.9a3.36,5.73 69.1,1 0,10.71 -4.09a3.36,5.73 69.1,1 0,-10.71 4.09z"/>
    <path android:pathData="M412.28,267.68c-8.12,16.19 -13.38,20.24 -24.81,22.09s-20.3,7.61 -30,5.55 -24.55,-2.18 -31.31,2.22 -23.11,5.12 -28.2,-2.67 7.56,-20.21 -13.58,-27.35 -8.91,-17.49 -9.43,-23.26 35.26,-146.61 35.26,-146.61S409.17,243.26 412.28,267.68Z"/>
    <path android:pathData="M364.99,258.69c-7.65,5.93 -25.16,7.41 -29.7,1.13s10.12,-37.34 8.94,-42.84S366.92,257.2 364.99,258.69Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="-23829.69236360679"
                android:endY="14347.815809669704"
                android:startX="-22772.94838332061"
                android:startY="15619.210907875986" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M337.87,216.91c-2.8,18.37 -10.34,41.82 -11,45.3s-12.54,4.4 -14.2,3.27 -5.12,-6.52 -5.62,-9.71 17.76,-53.12 17.63,-62.75S338.29,214.1 337.87,216.91Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="-35958.96457777922"
                android:endY="23870.056880797598"
                android:startX="-34822.417940097075"
                android:startY="25237.46455095114" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M302.93,251.19c-1,-9.31 18.71,-63.93 19.86,-68.14s-6.74,-48.43 -8.87,-51 -25.22,115.61 -28.39,125.15S303.47,256.41 302.93,251.19Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="-59348.73428439401"
                android:endY="38492.31322289459"
                android:startX="-57064.69410068067"
                android:startY="41240.299062277285" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M383.9,282.09a3.56,5.25 50,1 0,8.04 -6.75a3.56,5.25 50,1 0,-8.04 6.75z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M368.89,284.76a3.04,4.01 49.99,1 0,6.14 -5.16a3.04,4.01 49.99,1 0,-6.14 5.16z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M350.21,281.89a3.89,3.89 0,1 0,5.67 0.31A4,4 0,0 0,350.21 281.89Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M353.08,275.01a3.45,3.97 50.01,1 0,6.08 -5.1a3.45,3.97 50.01,1 0,-6.08 5.1z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M330.79,287.39a3.32,5.97 49.99,1 0,9.15 -7.68a3.32,5.97 49.99,1 0,-9.15 7.68z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M312.64,292.54a5.05,6.05 49.99,1 0,9.27 -7.78a5.05,6.05 49.99,1 0,-9.27 7.78z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M319.39,276.9a3.44,4.14 49.99,1 0,6.34 -5.32a3.44,4.14 49.99,1 0,-6.34 5.32z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M333.91,272.49a3.4,3.97 50.01,1 0,6.08 -5.1a3.4,3.97 50.01,1 0,-6.08 5.1z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M302.66,276.39a3.59,3.31 50,1 0,5.07 -4.26a3.59,3.31 50,1 0,-5.07 4.26z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M291.16,266.91a4.49,4.4 49.99,1 0,6.74 -5.66a4.49,4.4 49.98,1 0,-6.74 5.66z"/>
    <path android:pathData="M278.99,260.19c4,-7.56 7.41,-19.53 8.92,-26.76s21.3,-94.06 21.5,-97.7 -34.09,97 -32.85,121.56C276.77,261.53 278.22,261.64 278.99,260.19Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="-55928.14827754169"
                android:endY="37637.849972836644"
                android:startX="-54259.40447499727"
                android:startY="39645.55735541622" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M342.58,97.93c81,10.5 152.46,54.5 193.19,91S576.58,251.32 554.13,261.51s-36,12.15 -58.54,5.86 -51.28,-1 -64.09,-2.47 -49.67,16.44 -67.78,-5.14 -15.39,-52.71 -28.76,-74.66 -15.31,-31.14 -14.65,-43.24 -1.48,-19 -6.08,-20.14 12.42,-29.89 17.65,-31.39S333.35,96.73 342.58,97.93Z"/>
    <path android:pathData="M413.97,164.95c5.29,15.76 21.52,45.41 26.08,56s-24.14,15.92 -30.41,2.44 -22.88,-68.06 -20.24,-72.44S413.97,164.95 413.97,164.95Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="-34598.702241146886"
                android:endY="18103.94643493692"
                android:startX="-31260.24788354059"
                android:startY="22120.524324215807" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M376,146.34c5,14.55 24.24,77 27.81,85.56s-19.67,18.67 -26.72,5.11 -46.94,-117.82 -54,-131.37 51.48,39 51.48,39">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="-67848.02823146716"
                android:endY="30050.584265073852"
                android:startX="-58824.10943023778"
                android:startY="40907.48654653988" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M333.17,100.78c21.1,10 70.11,20.5 95.71,41.56s37.51,20.46 12.21,24 -107.61,-60.25 -111.57,-62.49S327.9,98.29 333.17,100.78Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="-41797.1653379003"
                android:endY="-5923.099251174289"
                android:startX="-30109.8514768665"
                android:startY="8138.200203867435" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M446.99,175.94c12,6.44 22.8,35.19 19.89,38.6s-19,8.27 -23.14,4.51 -20.86,-48.36 -20.86,-48.36S441.75,173.13 446.99,175.94Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="-18944.865248259666"
                android:endY="9367.691047330907"
                android:startX="-17085.87934606124"
                android:startY="11604.283455503028" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M508.32,184.57c9.65,10.65 31.66,32.57 26.74,43.9s-12,-1.44 -12,-1.44 -14.92,-33 -23,-40.22C504.14,183.03 508.32,184.57 508.32,184.57Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="-16278.763082910573"
                android:endY="11263.161082059054"
                android:startX="-14854.92910028262"
                android:startY="12976.21133826441" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M500.85,193.72c9.37,11.56 21.28,42.72 17.86,44.14s-7.44,2.64 -10.64,-1.17 -10.09,-32 -19.38,-40.39C492.28,188.66 496.37,188.2 500.85,193.72Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="-15487.338731640528"
                android:endY="10948.144590001408"
                android:startX="-14356.906162376416"
                android:startY="12308.1962716073" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M495.58,235.61c1.38,-15.76 -12.3,-37.86 -16.66,-42.2s-3.61,8.61 -3.66,14.12 11.22,33.55 12.29,34.82S494.46,248.84 495.58,235.61Z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="-18214.657744011314"
                android:endY="13683.401109895207"
                android:startX="-17505.168346588387"
                android:startY="14537.005539104775" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M539.42,220.56a8.31,5 50,1 0,7.66 -6.43a8.31,5 50,1 0,-7.66 6.43z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M539.61,206.41a5.52,3.32 50,1 0,5.09 -4.27a5.52,3.32 50,1 0,-5.09 4.27z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M539.68,239.95a8.84,4.6 49.99,1 0,7.05 -5.91a8.84,4.6 49.99,1 0,-7.05 5.91z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M518.41,249.07a8.31,4.24 50,1 0,6.5 -5.45a8.31,4.24 50,1 0,-6.5 5.45z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M501.17,251.37a7.37,4.05 49.99,1 0,6.2 -5.21a7.37,4.05 49.99,1 0,-6.2 5.21z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M468.89,238.53a9.11,5.25 50,1 0,8.04 -6.75a9.11,5.25 50,1 0,-8.04 6.75z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M450.75,235.44a8.84,3.04 50,1 0,4.66 -3.91a8.84,3.04 50,1 0,-4.66 3.91z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M438.47,245.67a7.21,3.04 49.99,1 0,4.66 -3.91a7.21,3.04 49.99,1 0,-4.66 3.91z"/>
    <path android:pathData="M480.01,190.11a8.38,7.55 50,1 0,11.57 -9.71a8.38,7.55 50,1 0,-11.57 9.71z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="-3130.029128123261"
                android:endY="-4652.796774757551"
                android:startX="-3303.987508677169"
                android:startY="-4445.481249770561" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M461.24,182.41a8.23,4.25 50.27,1 0,6.53 -5.43a8.23,4.25 50.27,1 0,-6.53 5.43z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="-2706.4789942711864"
                android:endY="-4320.571286349497"
                android:startX="-2844.395499782262"
                android:startY="-4154.640491057873" android:type="linear"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M461.3,161.21a7.1,4.66 50,1 0,7.14 -5.99a7.1,4.66 50,1 0,-7.14 5.99z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M541.35,253.78a4.23,2.82 50,1 0,4.32 -3.63a4.23,2.82 50,1 0,-4.32 3.63z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M554.01,246.45a4.05,2.39 49.99,1 0,3.66 -3.07a4.05,2.39 49.99,1 0,-3.66 3.07z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M559.39,238.52a5.52,2.03 49.99,1 0,3.11 -2.61a5.52,2.03 49.99,1 0,-3.11 2.61z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M523.68,261.3a5.66,2.62 50,1 0,4.01 -3.37a5.66,2.62 50,1 0,-4.01 3.37z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M512.87,261.31a4.28,2.35 50,1 0,3.6 -3.02a4.28,2.35 50,1 0,-3.6 3.02z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M499.1,261.9a4.83,2.35 50,1 0,3.6 -3.02a4.83,2.35 50,1 0,-3.6 3.02z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M488.86,256.75a4.56,2.49 50,1 0,3.81 -3.2a4.56,2.49 50,1 0,-3.81 3.2z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M468.7,254.26a6.08,3.47 50.01,1 0,5.32 -4.46a6.08,3.47 50.01,1 0,-5.32 4.46z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M452.91,250.91a6.04,2.49 49.99,1 0,3.81 -3.2a6.04,2.49 49.99,1 0,-3.81 3.2z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M434.01,258.87a6.25,4.42 50,1 0,6.77 -5.68a6.25,4.42 50,1 0,-6.77 5.68z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M416.49,256.93a5.21,3.59 50.02,1 0,5.5 -4.61a5.21,3.59 50.02,1 0,-5.5 4.61z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M412.73,244.01a5.39,3.73 49.99,1 0,5.71 -4.8a5.39,3.73 49.99,1 0,-5.71 4.8z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M399.25,259.38a4.97,3.45 50.02,1 0,5.29 -4.43a4.97,3.45 50.02,1 0,-5.29 4.43z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M380,259.61a5.52,3.73 50.01,1 0,5.72 -4.79a5.52,3.73 50.01,1 0,-5.72 4.79z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M496.78,179.67a5.8,3.59 49.99,1 0,5.5 -4.62a5.8,3.59 49.99,1 0,-5.5 4.62z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M489.28,165.22a5.1,2.83 50,1 0,4.34 -3.64a5.1,2.83 50,1 0,-4.34 3.64z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M458.27,145.73a4.97,3.22 50,1 0,4.93 -4.14a4.97,3.22 50,1 0,-4.93 4.14z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M424.37,129.03a5.73,3.36 50.01,1 0,5.15 -4.32a5.73,3.36 50.01,1 0,-5.15 4.32z"/>
    <path android:pathData="M386.58,13.46c-2.63,-3.71 -7.05,-3.68 -10.69,-3.36 -7.56,1.2 -13.86,5.53 -19.57,9.56 -19.33,15.12 -33.43,30.52 -37.17,34.18 -1.85,-2.41 -5.57,-1.05 -7.45,-0.62 -2.42,0.55 -4.41,-1.53 -6.09,-2.07a2,2 0,0 0,-2 0.94,352 352,0 0,0 -29.29,-38.1c-4.94,-5 -10.46,-10.36 -17.68,-13.07 -3.61,-0.86 -7.89,-2 -11.3,1.15 -2.63,4.06 0.42,8 2.45,10.73a19.55,19.55 0,0 0,8.87 6.1c1.62,0.34 3.76,1.13 5.54,-0.65 1.42,-1.84 0.82,-3.84 0.37,-5.39 -1.17,-3 -3.25,-6.07 -6.77,-6.54 -1.44,0 -3.82,0.31 -4,2.65a5.31,5.31 0,0 0,2.1 3.89c1.36,1.09 2.29,0.45 2.13,0.1 -0.06,-0.57 -0.31,-0.74 -1.09,-1.4 -1.74,-1.4 -2.33,-3.95 0.79,-3.58 2.24,0.17 4.37,2.72 5.33,5.36 1.35,3 -0.21,5.56 -3.82,4.08a18.13,18.13 0,0 1,-8.13 -5.45c-2,-2.43 -4.35,-6.12 -2.8,-8.8 2,-2.24 6.41,-2 9.58,-1 6.78,2.23 12.32,7.43 17.24,12.27 15,16.25 26,32.12 30.33,37.93 -0.73,1 0,2.49 -0.77,3.5 -1.19,1.53 -4,2.14 -5.39,6.79 -1.19,4 0.25,3.75 0.15,6.58s-1.65,1.1 -7.71,8.44 -0.4,8.22 0.85,15.35 -6.1,41.36 -12.38,65.93 -17.89,40.67 -20.63,62.87c-1.26,10.18 1.6,42.21 19.19,10.06s23.15,-70.07 27.29,-91.09c2.2,-11.16 7.6,-24.44 10.58,-33.53 3.42,-10.45 10.87,-11 11.72,-15.78s-3.08,-12.72 -4.68,-15.36 2,-5.23 2.4,-8.72 -2.31,-6.21 -3.93,-8.13 1,-2.72 -0.85,-5.24c3.93,-3.39 18.21,-18.32 37.28,-33.07 5.69,-4 12.05,-8.17 19.13,-9.45 3.27,-0.32 7.75,-0.12 9.46,2.42 1.38,2.76 -1.52,6.16 -4,8.22a18.07,18.07 0,0 1,-9 4.09c-3.81,0.88 -5.06,-1.78 -3.2,-4.59 1.38,-2.46 3.92,-4.63 6.17,-4.43 3.14,0.17 2.14,2.58 0.18,3.67 -1,0.57 -1.16,0.61 -1.32,1.19 -0.21,0.36 0.8,1 2.11,0.27a5.32,5.32 0,0 0,2.73 -3.46c0.2,-2.34 -2.08,-3.1 -3.5,-3.3 -3.53,-0.16 -6.1,2.45 -7.77,5.22 -0.72,1.44 -1.61,3.26 -0.65,5.32 1.36,2.1 3.63,1.75 5.27,1.7a19.55,19.55 0,0 0,9.74 -4.37C384.42,21.11 387.97,17.95 386.58,13.46Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M260.81,239.41a44.48,44.48 0,0 0,5.35 1.77c2.59,0.86 3.6,-1.19 1.45,-2.16s-6.17,-1.83 -7.42,-2.26S258.02,238.28 260.81,239.41Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M259.5,229.73c4.18,2.21 8.76,3.51 12.43,3.29 3.45,-0.21 3.29,-4.13 1.61,-5.17 -1.95,-1.21 -10.08,-4 -13.52,-3.11A2.66,2.66 0,0 0,259.5 229.73Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M262.33,216.41c5.07,-0.06 11.64,1.17 15.54,3.66 3.31,2.11 5.91,-5.56 0.79,-8.14a41.34,41.34 0,0 0,-14.77 -3.81C261.32,208.1 256.58,216.46 262.33,216.41Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M265.71,202.79c5.46,0.48 13.4,2.06 16.27,3.91s5.78,-2.64 2.23,-5.23 -12.86,-5 -16.57,-5.11S260.58,202.34 265.71,202.79Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M271.03,192.3a27.26,27.26 0,0 1,14 4.45c3.24,2.28 4.56,-4.1 1.8,-6.42 -3.65,-3.06 -13.12,-3.89 -15.33,-3.86S264.72,192.14 271.03,192.3Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M314.34,88.59a5.1,4.05 69.1,1 0,7.57 -2.89a5.1,4.05 69.1,1 0,-7.57 2.89z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M290.06,83.47a3.5,4.05 69.1,1 0,7.57 -2.89a3.5,4.05 69.1,1 0,-7.57 2.89z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M301.01,73.27m-2.23,0.85a2.39,2.39 119.48,1 1,4.47 -1.71a2.39,2.39 114.07,1 1,-4.47 1.71"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M302.57,66.61a3.31,2.03 69.1,1 0,3.79 -1.45a3.31,2.03 69.1,1 0,-3.79 1.45z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M310.13,76.29a2.39,4.05 69.1,1 0,7.57 -2.89a2.39,4.05 69.1,1 0,-7.57 2.89z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M313.7,64.12m-2.22,0.86a2.38,2.38 131.87,1 1,4.45 -1.72a2.38,2.38 124.67,1 1,-4.45 1.72"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M308.79,60.64a1.71,1.66 69.1,1 0,3.1 -1.18a1.71,1.66 69.1,1 0,-3.1 1.18z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M304.35,82.06c-4.81,12.18 -15.51,43.6 -9.85,58.51C300.72,131.6 308.58,93.07 304.35,82.06Z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71836/discussion-on-question-by-sergio-incorporar-svg-en-android).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que seleccionar la imagen .svg y convertirla a imagen vectorial, `vector asset`, ve al folder donde deseas la imagen y crea un nuevo `Vector Asset`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seleccionas la imagen .svg a convertir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te creará un archivo con extensión .xml, y contenido similar a :

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="M21.71,11.29l-9,-9c-0.39,-0.39 -1.02,-0.39 -1.41,0l-9,9c-0.39,0.39 -0.39,1.02 0,1.41l9,9c0.39,0.39 1.02,0.39 1.41,0l9,-9c0.39,-0.38 0.39,-1.01 0,-1.41zM14,14.5V12h-4v3H8v-4c0,-0.55 0.45,-1 1,-1h5V7.5l3.5,3.5 -3.5,3.5z"/>
</vector>
```

este puedes usarlo como recurso y cargarlo mediante su id usando `setImageResource()`, ejemplo:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_directions_white_48px);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Actualización:**

El error que obtienes específicamente al cargar esta imagen,

> Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line
>   0: invalid drawable tag gradient

refiere que existen propiedades no soportadas, en este caso **tienes que definir como mínimo `compileSdkVersion 24` y `targetSdkVersion 24`**

```
android {
    ...
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'      
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ...
    }

}
```

Con esto podrás mostrar el gráfico sin problemas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ver que el gráfico era una "mariposa", imagine era un dibujo complejo, en realidad ese no es el objetivo de los .svg para uso en un móvil, el procesamiento para generarlo requiere mucho trabajo del procesador.

Comment: Gracias Jorge, he realizado lo me que me has dicho y genera el xml sin ningún problema, pero al agregarlo al arreglo y correr la app me devuelve unfortunately, matgic has stopped

Comment: Actualiza el código en la pregunta Sergio, especificamente que error envia el LogCat

Comment: Gracias por tu valioso tiempo Jorge, he actualizado el código y  eso es lo que arroja el logcat

Comment: Exelente respuesta Jorge!

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag hey Bruno, gracias!, saludos!

Comment: si era el gráfico el del problema, con otro funciona a la perfección, gracias @Jorgesys

Comment: @Sergio excelente Sergio, hay que contemplar que los .svg no deberían ser tan complejos para una app móvil, de otra forma tendrían propiedades no soportadas en algunas apis , saludos!